# A term for a particular type of self-satisfaction

Tags: phrases, expressions

There's a particular type of self-satisfaction where a person feels good about themself because they see a flaw or a weakness in someone else. 
"I'm good because someone else is worse."

It often manifests itself in a religion context: feeling good because someone else is a "sinner".  It also manifests itself by feeling good because one is more clever or knows more than someone else.  It's the "beam" in the saying "Why do you see the mote in someone else's eye but not the beam in your own?"  Is there a word or term for it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the parable about the Pharisee who self-congratulated himself (while praying) for being righteous, compared to the tax collector who simply and honestly acknowledged his faults, [(Luke 18:9-14)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%2018%3A9-14&version=NASB) the implication is that he was self-righteous, trusting in himself instead of having real faith in God, which is what the tax-collector had.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many words, depending on the context.

For someone who thinks they know more than those around them, we could say:

## [smug](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/smug)

> too pleased or satisfied about something you have achieved or something you know:

The look is sometimes described as...

> ["**...looking like the cat that just got the canary**"](https://books.google.com.gt/books?id=qAX-hplFKoMC&q=%22like%20the%20cat%20that%20just%20got%20the%20canary%22&dq=%22like%20the%20cat%20that%20just%20got%20the%20canary%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y)

People of God are often described in the Bible as "righteous men" (or women, of course), but those who feel they stand on firmer moral ground than others around them can be termed as:

## [self-righteous](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/self-righteous)

> believing that your ideas and behaviour are morally better than those of other people

This word is not necesarily limited to a religious context: so-called "[Social Justice Warriors](https://www.google.com/search?q=SJW&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=qFdoWIHwA9DZ8gek1Z2wDQ)" also seem to fit into this category.

[Synonyms](https://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy-ab&client=firefox-b&biw=1024&bih=584&q=self%20righteous%20definition&oq=self%20righteous%20&gs_l=serp.1.2.35i39k1l2j0i20k1j0.8507.12613.0.15040.3.3.0.0.0.0.257.702.2-3.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.3.639.HTE7j_E54B0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.&bvm=bv.142059868,d.amc&ech=1&psi=71doWLqhNcPQjwSQlJ6oDQ.1483233307221.3&ei=_VdoWOqAPau_jwTDzKW4AQ&emsg=NCSR&noj=1&gfe_rd=cr) for this adjective include...

> **sanctimonious, self-satisfied, smug, priggish, complacent, pious, moralizing, preachy, superior, hypocritical; informal goody-goody**

But my favorite is "**holier-than-thou**", and for SNL fans, there is of course the [Dana Carvey characterization of the "Church Lady](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=church%20lady%20dana%20carvey)". For those of us who grew up under the very heavy hand of such moralyzing and preachy parents, there is no more apt portrayal than that.

Comment: The question asks to name the feeling not a name for one feeling it

Comment: qkris The OP specifically mentions self-satisfaction in the Q, and self-satisfied is listed as a synonym of self-righteous: the adjectives had no problem when made in comment, so whats the deal....?

Comment: There is not really an English word for the feeling associated with self satisfied due to the failings of others   Schadenfreude is a German word for it search this site for an interesting read on Schadenfreude.  All the words we have are adjectives describing the person who thus feels superior not the feeling itself

Comment: @Kris Schadenfreude is a fairly common usage in English and refers to the "pleasure taken in anothers misfortune". Even though English may be "deficient" in words to describe an exact feeling, we usually use a copulative verb to accompany the adjective to describe the feeling: ie She _feels_ sad. She _is_ sad. The feeling is sadness. So we just take the adjective and add an appropriate suffix to create the definition of the feeling. Examples: self-satisfaction, self-righteousness, self-righteous indignation, etc.

Comment: Yes you are right I wonder if OP will find any of this helpful

Comment: @Kris.  I've found the discussion and the links very helpful.  I don't think there is an expression that captures it  exactly but  "overweaningly smug" comes close.  It's expressed well in Luke 18:11 "God, I thank thee that I am not as other men are..."

Comment: @AlMaki I do not know who you want to apply the adjective to, but they must be an unbearably difficult person to be around.

Comment: Worth mentioning: [user116032](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/116032/user116032) did mention "smug" in a comment the day before you posted this. I'm not implying anything, but you may like to clarify or credit them.